# importError in Automator while running Python 3 script in shell /bin/bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, automation, importerror

I'm trying to add my python3 script to Automator using the shell /bin/bash, but keep getting the error:

```
"ImportError: No module named watchdog.observers”"
```

Which I assume is because it runs Python 2 and not 3. After searching on the internet I came up with the following ./bash_profile and shebang line, but it still does not seem to work. This is what I tired in the automator:

[image: Automator]

This is what my bash_profile looks like: 
[image: bash_profile]

And finally this is what the first lines in the Python script looks like:
[image: Python 3 script]

And when I then run the Automator I get the following error message:

[image: Error message]

Why do I get the import error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I solve it. In the Automator (shell /bin/bash) I did:

```
/Users/username/Documents/categorize_downloads.py
```

Before that I had change permissions on the file I wanted to run, so:

```
chmod 755 filename
```

And then finally I changed the shebang to:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

It seems to be cases when "env python3" could be used instead, but in this case I had to remove "env".